# Регулярки в Golang, получение стянутых данных посредствам парсера

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

в коде ниже приведен пример того, как я вытаскиваю из тега ссылку на фильм.

```
func (movie Movie) GettingData() {
    document := GetMarkupDoc(settings.IviAddress + "movies")

    link, _ := document.Find(".nbl-slimPosterBlock").First().Attr("href")

    fmt.Println(link)

Вовзращает:
C:\Go\src\Caretaker\processing>processing.exe
/watch/437652
```

Мне нужно получить то, что идет после последнего символа /, то есть 437652.
Я пробовал воспользоваться regexp, но как то не нашел способа обрезать строку регулярным выражением до того, что мне нужно.
Так же вот:

```
image, _ := document.Find(".image").First().Attr("style")
```

Здесь парсится путь к изображению из атрибута стайл.
На выходе:

```
background-image: url(https://адрес);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой библиотекой воспользоваться и как вытащить эти злополучные данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если эти данные относительно «скучные» и однообразные,
как в вашем случае, то регулярные выражения
не особо нужны:

```golang
const link = `/watch/1234`
fmt.Println(path.Base(link))
// Output:
//
//  1234

const style = `background-image: url(https://example.com/img.png);`
fmt.Println(strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimSuffix(style, `);`), `background-image: url(`))
// Output:
//
//  https://example.com/img.png
```

Второе можно оптимизировать, но это оставлено
в качестве домашнего задания :-) .

Если же данные более изощрённые, особенно
в *CSS*, вам понадобится как минимум токенайзер
*CSS*, а как максимум — парсер.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот регуляркой:

```
[^/]+$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5bad6

> /watch/**437652**
>
> https://regexr.com/**12345**